# DynamoDB: Is it possible to get the last element in the list datatype?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3, nosql

I have document that looks like as follows:

```
{'id': 123,
 'favorites': [5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 9, 2]}
```

In this document, favorite is of list type. I want to query the latest favorite or first/last 5 favorites. I'm not sure how can I achieve that in DynamoDB. Please help.

Comment: Show your query first.

Comment: I use boto3. So, my idea is to use get_item with projectionexpression using id=123, then using python's list comprehension to grab first/last item. I couldn't find anything equivalent to mongo's slice operator. This is not a homework question in case if you want to confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hunting for this question for a while, unfortunately it's not supported by the DynamoDB. May be, it'll be supported in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In current(22 Jun 2021) [example of documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html), they used `size(info.actors)` to get the size.

You can do this:

```
ConditionExpression='#list[0] = :num',
ConditionExpression='size(#list) = :num',
```

However, you CANNOT do this:

```
ConditionExpression='#list[ size(#list)-1 ] = :num',
```

According to
[boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item), it looks like it's impossible to get the last element.

The best work-around I've found so far is:

- reverse all lists, then use `#list[0]`
- use `contains(#list, :elem)`